# Not showing Project Structure in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am a new to IntelliJ IDEA and somehow my project structure doesn't appear where It should be. Someone know how to fix this please? I want it to appear left corner where red circle:

[image: structure]

Answer (score 3):

You have hidden the tool window buttons. To show them again press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> (and keep holding) or click on the bottom left corner icon. Or use `View` | **Tool Buttons** to show them permanently. Then you can click on the **Project** or **Structure** tool window buttons depending on what you need.

Another way is to use the menu: `View` | `Tool Windows` | **Project** (or **Structure**).

Or just use the keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> — Project
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> — Structure

You can find more details in the online documentation:

- [Manipulating the Tool Windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#show)

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder...Really helpful

Comment: Feel free to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helps.